# Installed MySQL, but it is not showing in the installer (Windows10)

Tags: windows-10, mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried installing MySQL from the official installer (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=492815).

I ran the installer, but I think the installer stopped someplace midway. Now, I am not able to see MySQL or MySQL workbench in my installed programs. When I try to run the installer again, I get this screen.

[Main page of the installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwLas.png)

When I try to 'Add' MySQL and MySQL Workbench from the installer, it shows that 'Another version of this package is already installed or scheduled to be installed' (screenshot below) even though no such version is showing up anywhere.

[Error being received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY81n.png)

Can someone help me with this very frustrating issue? I am sorry if I am missing something trivial here. I am very new to MySQL, and am struggling with this issue for over 2 days now.

Answer (score -1):

I found this in Microsoft's Forum, The first step will not work, of course, but the following ones, maybe.

**Step 1**

Uninstall MySQL from Control Panel. To do so, go to *Control Panel >Programs and Features > Select MySQL > Click on Uninstall*.

After you have uninstalled MySQL through Add/Remove programs, you now need to remove the existing database information which includes your actual data.  If you need any of that data, be sure to back it up. Next you can delete the data directory.

**Step 2**

Run Command Prompt as Administrator and execute the following command to stop and remove MySQL service.

```
Net stop MySQL
Sc delete MySQL
```

**Step 3**

Click on Start, type in *Show hidden files and folders*.

Select the *View* tab and select *Show hidden files and folders*.

Now explore the following locations and delete following folders.

- C:\Program Files\MySQL
- C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
- C:\ProgramData\MySQL

And if exists, delete the folder from the location.

- C:\Users[User-Name]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL

Restart your device and check the status.

The original post is here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-completely-uninstall-mysql/e90e1344-7b90-4319-8b2f-77b271ae66ed

I hope it help!

Comment: Answers should be self-contained and not simply contain a link to an external resource